# zyBooks Lab Activity 6.19 - Replacement Words

Tags: python

Having trouble with my output.
I'm fairly certain it's either my print statement or my sentence.replace coding.

Here's my code:

```
word_pairs = {}

tokens = input().split()
sentence = input()

step = 2
for index in range(0,len(tokens), step):
    key = tokens[index]
    value = tokens[index+1]
    
    word_pairs[key] = value
    for original, new in word_pairs.items():
        sentence = sentence.replace(original, new)
        
        print(sentence)
```

Here is the sample input:

```
automobile car   manufacturer maker   children kids

The automobile manufacturer recommends car seats for children if the automobile doesn't already have one.
```

Expected output:

```
The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the car doesn't already have one.
```

My output:

```
The car manufacturer recommends car seats for children if the car doesn't already have one.
The car manufacturer recommends car seats for children if the car doesn't already have one.
The car maker recommends car seats for children if the car doesn't already have one.
The car maker recommends car seats for children if the car doesn't already have one.
The car maker recommends car seats for children if the car doesn't already have one.
The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the car doesn't already have one.
```

Comment: Print after the for-loops when all replacements were done. Also, the second for-loop should be after the first, not in the first.

Comment: <insert face_palm emoji here>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't have time and just put the main ideas.

Explanation:

- I used the list slice "list[start:stop:step]" to get only the words to replace.
- Then I used a for loop and the replace method to replace the words ["automobile", "manufacturer", "children"] with the tokens list with index 1, 3 and 5.
  ["car", "maker", "kids"]

```
tokens = input().split()
sentence = input()
c = 1
for word in tokens[::2]:
  sentence.replace(word, tokens[c]) 
  c += 2

print(sentence)
"The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the car doesn't already have one."
```

or if you want use your solution, just adjust the indentation for print

```
word_pairs = {}

tokens = input().split()
sentence = input()

step = 2
for index in range(0,len(tokens), step):
    key = tokens[index]
    value = tokens[index+1]
    
    word_pairs[key] = value
    for original, new in word_pairs.items():
        sentence = sentence.replace(original, new)
        
 print(sentence)
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative approach that makes use of the enumerate() feature:

```
# words = ['automobile', 'car', 'manufacturer', 'maker', 'children', 'kids']
words = input().split()
# sentence = "The automobile manufacturer recommends...have one"
sentence = input()

for index, value in enumerate(words):
    # If the index is any even number to include 0:
    if index % 2 == 0:
        """ Replaces every even index value in words that is in sentence with
            the odd index value to the right of it. Example: "automobile" is 
            replaced by "car" then "manufacturer" by "maker", etc. """ 
        sentence = sentence.replace(value, words[index + 1])

print(sentence)
```

Usually, you try to avoid using literals within your code. However, for indexing purposes and the nature of this lab, this approach suffices and can maintain its accuracy no matter the number of word pairs you input.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your print function outside the loop

```
for index in range(0,len(tokens), step):
key = tokens[index]
value = tokens[index+1]

word_pairs[key] = value
for original, new in word_pairs.items():
    sentence = sentence.replace(original, new)
    
print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on this same project and I am having trouble. The input is the same as above but I have no output.
Here is my code if anyone could help.

```
    word_pairs = {}  # the dictionary of before/after words

    tokens = input().split()  # get words to find/replace
    sentence = input()  # the sentence to fix with word find/replace
    #print("Before: ", sentence)


    # Put word pairs into a dictionary as {key : value}  data pairs
    step = 2
    for index in range(0, len(tokens), step): # step by 2, since we deal with word 
    pairs
    #print( tokens[index],  tokens[index+1] )
    
    
    #key = tokens[index]
    #value = tokens[index+1]
    #print( key, ":", value ) # test
    
    
    #load the dictionary with K/V pairs:
    #word_pairs[key] = value
    
    #print(word_pairs)


    for original, new in word_pairs.items():
    #print(original, new)
    #sentence = sentence.""  # use string replace
    
    #print(sentence)
     "The car maker recommends car seats for kids if the car doesn't already have 
    one."
```